# $state.go fails to transition to nested state

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am building an app using AngularJS and injected `ui-router`module into my app. I have two `$stateProvider`states:

```
.state('app.search-patent', {
    url: '/search-patent',
    component: 'searchpatent',
    params: {
        navigation: 'patentnav'
    }
})
.state('app.search-patent.add-patent', {
    url: '^/add-patent',
    component: 'addpatent',
    params: {
        navigation: 'patentnav'
    }
})
```

And it my component controller, I want to re-direct the user once they click the submit button, as so:

```
var vm = this;

vm.findPatent = function(patentNo) {
    searchPatentService.findPatent(patentNo)
    .then(
        function(data) {
            vm.patent = data;
            $timeout(function() {
                $state.go('app.search-patent.add-patent', {obj: vm.patent});
                    }, 2000);   
            },
            function(errResponse) {
                console.error('Error while finding patent');
            }
    );
}
```

My issue is that is isn't directing the user to the specified page. Before `add-patent` was a child state of `search-patent` it re-directed the user perfectly fine. The URL changes accordingly but the page stays on the `search-patent` template. I have other states that are child states and haven't had this issue. I am probably over looking something very simple and obvious.

***Question***

How do I get `$state.go` to re-direct the user to the `add-patent` page?

Comment: Even state is also changing. You must be able to see bothy parent and child view after `$state.go('app.search-patent.add-patent', {obj: vm.patent});
                    }, 2000);   `

Comment: Do you have verbose output from ui-router enabled, think that might leave a clue, search `$trace` on https://ui-router.github.io/guide/ng1/migrate-to-1_0

Comment: Think @Ved might be on to something, if add-patent is suppose to replace the search view you might want to rename `'app.search-patent.add-patent'` to `'app.add-patent'`

Comment: A hack for this is, put your parent bcomponent inside <div ui-view>Parent goes here</div>.

Comment: @Ved think that leaves op unable to navigate back to the parent once the ui-view is populated, so would vote against such hack :)

Comment: Yeah, all my other nested views don't replace the parent view, just add to it with `ui-view`. I will have a look into what you guys have suggested

Comment: @cYrixmorten navigate back should work. I need to test it.

Comment: Reason being I had `add-patent` as child is I need to access the `$stateParams` of the parent.... would you recommend using a service to accomplish this if I remove `search-patent` as a child state?

Comment: `$stateParams` should still be accessible, since it seems you pass the same params to `add-patent`. If you use ui-router >= 1.0 you can also inject the `$transitions` service to access the previous state model.

Comment: Also, again if ui-router >= 1.0, the params can be access using `$transition$` service: `$transition$.params()['someParam']`. Cannot remember the details but afaik is the recommended approach.

Comment: Got it working. Thank you to you both. @cYrixmorten I have got it working with `$state.go` but that was down to your comment of $stateParams being accessible. I will have a look at `$transition` soon. If you leave an answer I'll happily mark it as correct. Thank you

Comment: Awesome ;) think it will leave a better answer if you write the specifics that solved you issue in an answer of your own and mark it as accepted :)

Comment: True point! Thanks again